# using splice inside 2D Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created this 2D array, and I'm trying to delete the rows that are having 5 "ones" or more,
I tried it with splice (a.splice(j,1)) but it doesn't work . I think because when using this method it changes the whole quantity of rows and that's affects the for loops.

Is it because I don't use splice correctly or should I use different method ?

Thanks !

```js
a = Array(7).fill(0).map(x => Array(10).fill(0))

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  a[1][i + 2] = 1;
  a[4][i + 2] = 1;
  a[5][i + 2] = 1;
}

console.log(a);


let count = 0;
for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (a[j][i] == 1) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }
  if (count > 4) {
    console.log("Line" + j);
    // a.splice(j,1);
  }
  count = 0;
  // a.splice(j,1);
}
```

Comment: You can create a new array with filtered values and use it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `splice` is correct but you move forward through the array (`j` is incremented). To do this type of operation you need to move backward through the array (`j` is decremented) - this way the changing array indices don't intefere with your loop.

See the example below:

```js
a = Array(7).fill(0).map(x => Array(10).fill(0))

for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  a[1][i+2] = 1;
  a[4][i+2] = 1;
  a[5][i+2] = 1;
}

console.log("Original array");
console.log(a);

for (let j = a.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
  var count;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < a[j].length; i++) {
    if (a[j][i] === 1) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
  
  if (count > 4) {
    a.splice(j, 1);
  }
  
  count = 0;
}

console.log("Filtered array");
console.log(a);
```